# How to integrate Metronics frontend template in Meteor

Tags: html, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am newbie to Meteor. I have following small piece of code from Metronics front-end template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

I know little bit that Meteor inserts some HTML code by itself and prohibits to do manually. Can some one guide me how can I insert above mentioned code in my template.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Check [Inject-Initial](http://atmospherejs.com/gadicohen/inject-initial) package, it allows you modify HTML before sending.

#### HACKY way:

Meteor doesn't support custom doctypes or html comments.

However If you can replace **[WebApp](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/webapp)** package with your forked version containing updated **boilerplate.html** with html comments then that should work, but it will be hack.

### WebApp package

**boilerplate.html** :

```
<html {{htmlAttributes}}>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
<body>
  {{{body}}}
</body>
</html>
```

Source : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/webapp/boilerplate.html

**webapp_server.js** (line 490 to 497):

```
    var boilerplateData = _.extend({htmlAttributes: htmlAttributes},
                                   boilerplateBaseData);
    var boilerplateInstance = boilerplateTemplate.extend({
      data: boilerplateData
    });
    var boilerplateHtmlJs = boilerplateInstance.render();
    boilerplateByAttributes[attributeKey] = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
          HTML.toHTML(boilerplateHtmlJs, boilerplateInstance);
```

Source : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/webapp/webapp_server.js

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your <head> in meteor:

```
<head>
    <!--[if IE 8]> <meta name="ie-8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9]> <meta name="ie-9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE]> <meta name="is-ie"> <![endif]-->
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
    <meta content="" name="MyApp"/>
    <meta content="" name="MyCompany"/>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

You can create a new html file or add the above to your existing template.

Next add the following to your template helper coffee/js file:

```
Template.hello.rendered = ->
  $('html').attr 'lang', 'en'
  if $('meta[name=\'ie-8\']').length
    $('html').attr 'class', 'ie8'
    $('head').append '<meta content="" name="ie8"/>'
  if $('meta[name=\'ie-9\']').length
    $('html').attr 'class', 'ie9'
    $('head').append '<meta content="" name="ie9"/>'
  if $('meta[name=\'is-ie\']').length
    $('head').append '<meta content="" name="is-ie"/>'
  else
    $('head').append '<meta content="" name="not-ie"/>'
  return
```

After your template has been rendered this will search for a meta:name and react accordingly. You can add attributes to the html, or add content to the head.

According to the meteor documentation:

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp

> HTML files in a Meteor application are treated quite a bit differently from a server-side framework. Meteor scans all the HTML files in your directory for three top-level elements: <head>, <body>, and <template>. The head and body sections are separately concatenated into a single head and body, which are transmitted to the client on initial page load.

The result of the above will be:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="__meteor-css__" href="/6176b8b829c9df965e358642efa91f9fb2d91b51.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">__meteor_runtime_config__ = {"meteorRelease":"METEOR@1.0.3.1","ROOT_URL":"http://localhost:3000/","ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX":"","appId":"reg9gp1tr7xjw1ia7u0e","autoupdateVersion":"a00b33a70d60e865c9f096b9c3e8a9f5386ed45c","autoupdateVersionRefreshable":"79d3c80e832e7e5b97b84f80da47f9571b97f8a7","autoupdateVersionCordova":"none"};</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18"></script>
    ...
    <title>Meteor App</title>
    <!--[if IE 8]> <meta name="ie-8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9]> <meta name="ie-9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE]> <meta name="is-ie"> <![endif]-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <meta content="" name="Agent Online">
    <meta content="" name="Online Travel Services AG">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&amp;subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta content="" name="not-ie">
</head>
```